# Call without pressing the call button

Tags: android

I start a call intent like this :

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+numberToCall));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

but instead of directly calling that number I see the calling screen with the number prefilled  and I have to press the call button in order to call. Is it possible to call directly without having to press the call button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dial number by using the [CALL_PHONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE) permission. For other, privileged, numbers use the [CALL_PRIVILEGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PRIVILEGED) permissison.

Comment: That was the one! Thank you Raghav!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your manifest. It will allow you to call a phone without prompt

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

> CALL_PHONE:   Allows an application to initiate a phone call without going through the Dialer user interface for the user to confirm the call being placed.

Which can be found here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Ahh .. it seems it happens because I try to call an emergency number and according to docs .. you can't directly call one .. am I right?

Comment: @TrimbitasSorin Yep, I am already aware of that thanks :). Your question never asked about emergency numbers, so my answer never mentioned it, as its not a common desire.

Comment: My mistake for the question, didn't knew that there are differences in handling them.